# Google My Business API not found on the library

Tags: google-business

My web app have recently been approved to use the Google My Business API, when I login to my Google Cloud Library for the related project to enable the API, I could't find the the Google My Business API.

Can anyone tells how to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the list of project APIs, it is shown as "**Google My Business API**".

[image: The list of project APIs, including the "Google My Business API"]

[The list of project APIs, including the "Google My Business API"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q7vW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with your corporate email account?

Faced a similar problem when I tried to enable Business Messages API. Then I realized
google business won't allow generic email addresses for the allow list and we have to share individual corporate accounts for APIs access and developer console access.